# Side-to-Side figures with a sidebar [beamer]

Tags: beamer, floats, minipage, textwidth, sidebyside

I am doing a Beamer presentation and I am trying to put two figures next to each other using *minipage*. The problem is that my presentation contains a right sidebar and when I set the minipage width to *.5\textwidth* the two figures seem to be centred around the centre of the page, ignoring the sidebar on the right. In a sense, I would like the *textwidth* to take in account the presence of the sidebar. Here is the piece of code I'm struggling with :

```
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme[right]{sidebar}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Problem 1}

\begin{frame}{Problem 1}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
  \includegraphics[scale=.25,angle=-90]{image1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
  \includegraphics[scale=.25,angle=-90]{image2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

- Use `width=\textwidth` (or `height=\textwidth` if rotated by 90°) for the images and it works fine.
- Use `example-image` to get a MWE.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme[right]{sidebar}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{document}

\section{Problem 1}

\begin{frame}{Problem 1}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=\textwidth,angle=-90]{example-image}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it was actually really helpful! Now, how can I make the image bigger while keeping them centred?

Comment: Why do you want to make the images bigger? By setting them to `\textwidth` you get the maximum size (without overlapping each other or the borders).

Answer (score 1):

`beamer` has an environment for that: `columns`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme[right]{sidebar}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{document}


\section{Problem 1}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Problem 1}

\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
  \includegraphics[scale=.25,angle=-90]{example-image-a}
\end{column}%
\begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
  \includegraphics[scale=.25,angle=-90]{example-image-b}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]